# XML to Table / CSV

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I want to convert xml files into the csv format, my problem is i don't get the correct table form.
There are tons of examples in the web, but i couldn't find any example / solution for my xml structure.

current code:

```
[xml]$inputFile = Get-Content $xmlpath
$inputFile.Import.Category.Record.ChildNodes | Export-Csv $csvpath -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter:";" -Encoding:UTF8
```

What i get:

```
"FieldName";"String"
"Field1";"111"
"Field2";"222"
"Field1";"333"
"Field2";"444"
```

What i need:

```
"Field1";"Field2"
"111";"222"
"222";"333"
```

XML:

```
<Import xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Category>
    <Record>
      <Field FieldName="Field1"> 
        <String>111</String>
      </Field>
      <Field FieldName="Field2">
        <String>222</String>
      </Field>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <Field FieldName="Field1"> 
        <String>333</String>
      </Field>
      <Field FieldName="Field2">
        <String>444</String>
      </Field>
    </Record>
  </Category>
</Import>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate each `Record`, create a [`PSObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject?view=pscore-6.2.0), then add the `FieldName` and `String` properties with [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-7):

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path .\test.xml

& {
    foreach ($record in $xml.DocumentElement.Category.Record) {
        $psObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject
        foreach ($field in $record.Field) {
            $psObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $field.FieldName -NotePropertyValue $field.String
        }
        $psObject
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path .\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**output.csv**

```
"Field1","Field2"
"111","222"
"333","444"
```